# Separate login pages from general pages

Tags: magento-1.9, web-services, plugin

On my website I have homepage, Page 1, Page 2 and Page 3. Now there are subpages in Page 1 and Page 2 which I want visitors to first login (by site registration or through social media account)and then view further content. After logged-in, they can view all the subpage's content of only Page 1 and Page 2. For Page 3 different loginID is required. How to do it? is there any plugin to control that?

Comment: Take a look at http://bit.ly/CustomLoginRedirectPro & http://bit.ly/StoreRestrictionPro